# Promote a website on social media using domain redirect to avoid being marked as spam

Tags: google-adsense-policies, website-promotion

I have a website and I want to promote it on different social media platform. However, I don't want  to be treated like spammer and get banned. Can I use another domain to promote my website?

For example, I will use other domain to redirect to my original website's landing page.  That page is specially designed to attract users.

Are such redirects wrong?   If so is there any other way I can promote my site?  I did not put any Adsense code on my landing page because I'm afraid that using redirects to it would violate the Adsense policy.

Comment: Why are you worried about being seen as a spammer?   Many websites use social media for promotion.    If the subject of your website isn't something that can be posted to social media, I don't think redirects are going to help.

Comment: website is about product reviews such as gadgets and other accessories. using domain redirects to get traffic is it violate the  ad sense policy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a website and I want to promote it on different social media platform. However, I don't want to be treated like spammer...

Don't make your website look like something terrible to people and then you won't be treated like one

> Can I use another domain to promote my website? ... website is about product reviews such as gadgets and other accessories.

If you had some wonderful website with different major sections, then I'd say yes have multiple domain names pointing to quality content.

> For example, I will use other domain to redirect to my original website's landing page. That page is specially designed to attract users.  Are such redirects wrong?

Take a look at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721311?hl=en

They describe your intention of new domains as "doorway" pages because the first page (which is the new domain) offers no useful content, only a way to get to the next page (a.k.a. doorway). It is nice that you cut part of the inconvenience to the users by not making them click a lonely link for them to get to the real content but there is still inconvenience because users have to first wait for content (the redirection) to load from the new domain then they have for the real page to load. Why not just ditch the inconvenience and have users wait for only ONE page rich in content to load?

> If so is there any other way I can promote my site?

Talk to people? Make rich quality content that people want to see, and use search analytics in google search console to see what queries people use and how many enter your site as a result.

Comment: 301 redirection is not consider as doorway pages. Doorway pages are another thing,  for example if I search anything for specific location and I will land to one specific webpage, and If I do another search query with different location name, and I see different title and snippet in search result but when I click on it, then I will land to same page then it is doorway pages. Doorway pages and 301 redirection is two different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense works fine for any referral traffic if advertiser is happy with that traffic. When some post goes viral in social media, and drive million of pageviews in just one day, then still Adsense works fine for particular website, but for low quality traffic(by promoting everywhere) they will bann you, It's all about the quality of traffic.

Social Media website use scrapers just like spider bot, and they follow 301 redirection just like any other. So they already see your main domain, no matter how much domain or redirection you just setup.

Most people shared their URL with shorten URL service like goo.gl or bit.ly, and social media scrapers will automatically follow the redirection and will display snippet according to destination page.

So their is no any benefits you will get if you just setup 301 redirection with new domain to your main website.